# is the @ operator for matrix multiplication automatically choosing the dimensions of its inputs?

Tags: python, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication

Consider this simple example

```
X = np.array([[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]])

X.shape
Out[126]: (3, 3)

X
Out[127]: 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3]])
```

and let's define a column vector

```
b = np.array([1,1,1])
b.shape
Out[128]: (3,)

b_col = np.array([1,1,1]).reshape(-1,1)
b_col.shape
Out[129]: (3, 1)
```

Now, according to the rules of matrix multiplication:

`X@b_col.T` does not work (error: the dimensions do not match)

`X@b_col` gives the correct result (a 3x3 matrix times a 3x1 vector = 3x1 vector)

```
Out[132]: 
array([[3],
       [6],
       [9]])
```

however,

```
X@b
Out[133]: array([3, 6, 9])
```

returns the correct vector but without row/column information. Is @ automatically choosing that the multiplication can only work if `b` is considered as a `column` vector?

Thanks!

Comment: especially: signature `(n,k),(k,m)->(n,m)`. i.e. the last entry of the shape of the first argument needs to match the first entry of the second argument.

Comment: "If the second argument is 1-D, it is promoted to a matrix by appending a 1 to its dimensions. After matrix multiplication the appended 1 is removed."